# What drawbacks does xterm has?

Tags: terminal

Why there are so many terminal emulators claim that they were designed to replace 'xterm'? What disadvantages does xterm has?
Tell me as simply as you can,a few words is enough,I don't want to read much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xterm is extremely old and not very feature rich. I suggest actually trying it out, and comparing it to a more modern terminal emulator.

Comment: ??? It's got many more features than most of the bloatware terminals (like `gnome-terminal` or `konsole`) around. Granted it doesn't do transparency or tabs, but it has all the features that matter (in addition to being a lot faster and not pulling hundreds of mega-bytes of dependency) and is extremely customisable.